# Pandas - xls to xlsx converter

Tags: pandas, xlsx, xls

I want python to take ANY .xls file from given location and save it as .xlsx with original file name? How I can do that so anytime I paste file to location it will be converted to xlsx with original file name?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
    
for filename in os.listdir('./'):
 if filename.endswith('.xls'):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df.to_excel(??)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be perfectly fine. In case you are only missing the correct way to write it with the given name, here you go.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
    
for filename in os.listdir('./'):
 if filename.endswith('.xls'):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df.to_excel(f"{os.path.splitext(filename)[0]}.xlsx")
```

A possible extension to convert any file that gets pasted inside the folder can be implemented with an infinite loop, for instance:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time

while True:
    files = os.listdir('./')
    for filename in files:
        out_name = f"{os.path.splitext(filename)[0]}.xlsx"
        if filename.endswith('.xls') and out_name not in files:
            df = pd.read_excel(filename)
            df.to_excel(out_name)
            
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: @mlange Thanks a lot! I understand that f" means beginning of the string? and os.path.splitext(filename) takes file's path and divide it between name and ext?

Comment: I'm happy that the proposed solution helps. F-Strings are a certain type of strings in Python providing an easy way to format strings. If you want to know more about them, please see the [official documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). `os.path.splitext` behaves exactly as you mentioned.